# Show overlay on top when zoom out in OpenLayers 4.6.5?

Tags: openlayers, angular

I have a tile layer, three vector layers.  The tile layer has lots of overlays in it. I want to put vector layers on top when zooming out the map using OpenLayers 4.6.5. I tried to apply setLayerIndex and raiseLayer, but it says it is not a function of OlMap. Is there a way to get this done?

**Layer instantiations:**

```
initializeMap() {
    this.source = new OlVector({});
        this.clusterSource = new OlCluster({
          distance: this.distance,
          source: this.source
        })

        this.layer = new OlVectorLayer({
          style: (f, r) => this.styleFunction(f, r),
          source: this.clusterSource,
        });

        this.dockLayer = new OlVectorLayer({
          style: (f, r) => this.styleDockFunction(f, r),
          source: new OlVector({}),
        });

        this.countLayer = new OlVectorLayer({
          style: (f, r) => this.styleLabelFunction(f, r),
          source: new OlVector({})
        });





        let tileLayer = new OlTileLayer({
          source: new OlXYZ({
            crossOrigin: null,
            url: 'https://cartodb-basemaps-{a-c}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
          })
        });


        let view = new OlView({
          center: OlProj.fromLonLat([5.73271, 58.96564]),
          zoom: mapZoomLevel,
        });

        this.map = new OlMap({
          interactions: OlInteraction.defaults().extend([
            new PinchZoom()
          ]),
          layers: [tileLayer, this.layer, this.dockLayer, this.countLayer],
          view: view
        });
}
```

**Marker additions to map follows:**

```
createMarker(pos, txt, color1, txt2, color2, dockingStationId) {
    let elem = this.marker.nativeElement.cloneNode(true);
    elem.querySelector("#marker-txt").innerHTML = txt;
    elem.querySelector("#docking-station").innerHTML = dockingStationId;
    elem.querySelector("#marker-txt").style.backgroundColor = color1;
    elem.querySelector("#marker-txt2").innerHTML = txt2;
    elem.querySelector("#marker-txt2").style.backgroundColor = color2;

    var marker = new OlOverlay({
      position: pos,
      positioning: 'center-center',
      element: elem
    });
    this.map.addOverlay(marker);

  }
```

Comment: You can set `zIndex` property when defining layer and then later dynamically change it by `setZIndex` layer method.

Comment: @TomazicM I did it, but nothing got changed, maybe I'm missing something, can you provide me an example for me?

Comment: Can you provide non working example for me?